# Django powered site and micro sites – do I have to create a separate project for each microsite?

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

I'm looking to build a Django website with the main site on `example.com`. On this domain, a user can register using an email and password and start writing blog posts at `example.com/blog`. Admins will be able to login into the Django Admin to alter posts and change content on the other pages of `example.com`.

The website will have one microsite each year on subdomains, e.g., `2013.example.com`, `2014.example.com`, etc. Admins will be able to edit content using the Django Admin.

I'm going to deploy the Django project onto Heroku.

The question that I would answered is whether I should create a new Django app and Heroku deployment for each microsite and the main site? Or, whether I can create it all as one Django project?

The latter seems to make more sense to me, but unsure how I would go about it.

Comment: Have a look at Django sites: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: @allcaps Thank you for the reply, do you know a better place to post questions like this to?  I felt that my question was a little vague.

Comment: I think SO is fine. There is a Django IRC channel and users mailing list. https://www.djangoproject.com/community/